# How to keep the public from finding a trans-reality inter-dimensional space bridge in your backyard, and how to keep stuff from coming out

Tags: dimensions, concealment

In one of my stories, three ex-SWAT team people have been recruited to guard a trans-reality inter-dimensional space bridge (basically means aliens can walk through it)in the backyard of a large house. the last people who were guarding it either died or are too old to guard it now, which is why the three people have been recruiting. They're main job is to keep it quiet from the rest of the world, but they are also required to keep any bad stuff from coming out. They were also told to help anyone who needs it, as long as their end goal isn't evil.

Assume that technology is the same as it is now, they can't go through the space bridge to get futuristic weapons, and that they can only use stuff they can acquire legally on earth(no tanks, fighter jets, or mortars). The location of the space bridge isn't set in stone yet, but I'm assuming you'd want it in a small town(we already now what happens when you open a portal over new york from avengers).

The house they are living in is magical, and will notify everyone if the portal activates to let something through, or if a concerned citizen walks over wondering why everyone is yelling and setting off fireworks at 3 am in September.

So the big question is- how should I keep people from finding out aliens could come out of your backyard, and how does one keep the aliens from coming through?

Comment: As for hiding it, why not just build a shed over it?

Comment: I apologize for doing it, but this is storybuilding, not worldbuilding. Worldbuilding is about creating and consistently using the rules and systems of a world wherein an infinite number of stories can be told. Storybuilding is about plot, circumstances, and character actions and choices. By the time you provided all the details needed to make this worldbuilding (political structures, demographics, geography, physiology/tech/ideologies of all aliens, etc.) you'd answer your own question.

Comment: Who is 'they'? Who guards the portal? The US government, the Illuminati, the MIB?

Comment: @Halfthawed, thee ex-SWAT agents. not sponsored by the government in any way.

Comment: Set an iris a few microns from the event horizon

Comment: @Ceramicmrno0b It's just three guys who are arbitrarily deciding to guard a portal? They don't have the means or resources to realistically keep this concealed from the general public. Or the government.

Comment: @Halfthawed, they can use whatever falls through the portal. space junk, random bits of advanced technology, the occasional gold bar.

Comment: @JBH I disagree with some more details such as, what are the capabilities of those coming through? Does the portal drop items that don't fit to the nearest space or do they fail to come through?  we can realistically come up with a solution on /how/ they can guard it. this has no difference than questions like how to defend my villain lair against superpowered heroes. or what zombie proof defenses can I make?

Comment: @Ceramicmrno0b What happens when the portal is completely encased? do things appear nearby? does the portal destroy nearby structures? could we literally just build a concrete pillar where a portal used to be? what limitations does this magic portal have?

Comment: @ITAlex the OP didn't ask how to guard it. The OP asked how to keep people from finding out aliens could come out of your backyard. That's a HUGE difference that extends well beyond mere guarding of the portal.

Comment: @JBH that still is a logistical issue and not a story issue.

Comment: @ITAlex It's a story issue because it depends too much on story elements the OP has not provided. ([Please read.](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3300/49)) The argument "what is story-base" has gone on for years. The reality is, if undefined circumstances affect the answers, it's story-based.

Answer (score 2):

Hiding it isn't the problem, nor is physical security. These are mundane, even boring problems.

Their problem is one of intelligence. In relation to both of your stated concerns.

For instance, building some sort of cover so that snoopy neighbors don't see it... simpletons could manage that. They often do, if only for more nefarious reasons like hiding illicit drug manufacturing. And just like those criminals have trouble with intelligence operations (DEA, FBI, ATF, etc) so too would your space bridge guards have a hell of a time preventing anyone from knowing.

If this were an operation run by (just an example) the CIA, they'd come up with cover identities for those operatives. Ones that plausibly explain why they live in that house and stay there nearly 24/7. Do you have such? They'd have a support team on the constant lookout for counter-intelligence. Weird people showing up and performing surveillance, etc. But your guys can't do that themselves (even if they'd know to do it), because they're busy guarding the portal so Cthulhu doesn't sneak in.

And intelligence operations feature in the "don't let the bad guys come through" directive. How would they know who's bad? Are they supposed to let anyone in that looks cuddly, and keep the scary-looking ones out? They'd need an entire agency, a large one, just performing intelligence to even be able to guess which ones are the good guys and which are the bad. And in turn that large agency would have to send dozens of operatives through just to do scouting and recon, to engage in and perform intelligence operations. Quite likely there'd even need to be some sort of diplomatic outreach before they could manage some of those.

They are understaffed, underskilled, and don't even have enough coverage to keep full 3 shifts running (let alone with more than one man on duty at a given time). This is a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: So you're saying a security team would be platoon-sized? This would comprise 4-man team x 4 shifts of 5 8-hour days, a commander, 1 or 2 clerks, & 1 electronics/systems guy. Maybe even more staff? In that case, don't build a shed, construct a fake warehouse around it.

Comment: @llywrch Platoon-sized minimum, just for guard duty. They probably want a heavy machine gun aimed at the portal, all sandbagged up. Then, if you want to keep it a secret, you need at least as many people looking outward from it (and trying to be inconspicuous). Warehouse might work, especially if you can drive big trucks into and out of it constantly.

Answer (score 1):

#### Mundane Security

To keep something like a portal hidden at a basic level can be achieved by hiding it physically and distancing it from others.  Building a shed around it and placing it on a property at the edge of town are two good places to start.  A larger propery at the edge of a town is not going to look that odd -- it could be a slice of a farm that a house was built on.

The third layer of security is to generate a situation where nobody needs to go back there or poke into the portal shed in the first place.  An abandoned lot would invite kids to try to break into it on a dare.  Given that there are three people there, they could just be friends living together and enjoying the single life.  Even with a backyard BBQ going on, a locked shed should not be something people need to look inside.

If the portal can be moved, putting it in the basement of the guardian's house is an option as well.  The trick will be to stop curious houseguests from investigating the locked basement.  But people do like their privacy so it's not that outlandish to lock the basement door.

#### Worldbuiding

From the question, it looks like the world is being built from this point and expanding out.  I could be wrong, but the lack of additional information surrounding the world leads me to that conclusion.

The question implies the existence of magic (or advanced tech) in the form of a proximity ward on the property.
From there, I think it is prudent to decide to what level this magic/tech exists in our world.  Is it reasonable that there is more on the property than just an alert ward to keep the area safe?

Why can't the three guardians not get items from the other side of the portal?  If they are more advanced in some aspect than us, it would make sense to be able to do that, if only to either guard the portal or give the denizens of the other side some home comforts.  My inclination is that the portal is one-way, but that might not be the case.

Another bit of worldbuiding is deciding what came first, the portal or the house.  It sounds a bit silly as a question, but it might be relevant to the situation.  Building a structure around an exposed portal is a bit different than somebody building interdimensional portals in their own backyard (using ordinary household materials).

All in all, there is plenty of other worldbuilding that can be done around this one situation.  Some of it might actually help yourself or one of us answer the question better.